# Java enhanced for loop and IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, loops, selenium, indexoutofboundsexception

How come that I am getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while using Java enhanced for loop?My code looks like this

```
for (WebElement input : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']"))) {
    if (input.isDisplayed()) {
        input.clear();
    }
}
```

It uses Selenium WebDriver to find all `<input type="text" />` tags and clear they content if they are displayed (otherwise it would throw a different exception). And in some tests I get

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
```

Rest of the stack trace is on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1iPSBDvU).

**EDIT**

This error still occurs even if I add the check for array emptiness

```
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']"));
if (!inputs.isEmpty()) {
     for(WebElement input : inputs) {
     }
}
```

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with the `Iterator` returned by `driver.findElements()`.

Comment: I kind of figured this out but still - how should I handle this situation properly?

Comment: Are you perhaps running an old version of Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
```

This specifies that you have entered the loop, at index 1, although the size of the array is 0. You should enter at index 0. Which is strange. So this would indicate that the error is being thrown by *see below*

---

Try and run some debugging - Before this, try and print the object which is returned by

```
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']"))
```

and try and see if anything is actually returned.

I would have commented but don't have enough rep.

Also it's a for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the result of this statement `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']"))`.

It seems `driver.findElement`s is getting indexOutOfBound exception even before enhanced loop start to execute. Can you try to debug or print the value on console.